# Crawled properties vs Managed Properties

Tags: managed-property, crawl, crawled-property

I have added a managed metadata site column to a custom list. The crawled property will automatically be created after first crawl. My question is when the managed property will be created?

Second question is: where in central admin i can see newly created crawl and manage property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Crawled properties are generated automatically by SharePoint while crawling published content that has the corresponding fields populated. For example, in order to get a CrawledProperty for "MyColumn", you need to have at least one item that has a value in that column.
After the next "Full Crawl", a Crawled Property for "MyColumn" will be created with a kind of Hungarian notation naming convention, typically something like "ows_MyColumn" or "ows_TEXT_MyColumn", etc. depending on the data type.

Managed Properties are *sometimes* automatically created by SharePoint based on the Crawl properties, mapping a specific crawled property to the Managed Property. 
For example: In the above scenario a Managed Property *may* be created with a name like "OWSMyColumn" and have a mapping to the "ows_MyColumn" Crawled Property.

In SharePoint 2010 it was possible to configure the Search Service to automatically generate Managed Properties for each found Crawled Property, as explained here:

http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-turn-off-auto-generated-managed.html

In SharePoint 2013, *in theory* the Managed Properties should be always automatically created, but I've seen that not happening sometimes. You can do this manually from Central Admin as explained in this TechNet article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667(v=office.15).aspx

Another alternative to create *both* Crawled Properties and Managed Properties without requiring content creation and a search crawl, is to use PowerShell.
This post has sample code that will create the 2 types:

http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2014/02/powershell-script-for-creating-and.html

Comment: any idea where i can find the code in sharepoint 15 hive?